# Возврат указателя на файл через FFI

Tags: ruby, rust, ffi

Есть скрипт на ruby, использующий функцию в либе через интерфейс внешних функций. Либа написана на Rust и работает с изображениями: открывает картинку, выполняет над ней действия и возвращает на нее указатель.

Как можно правильно обработать этот указатель на стороне ruby? Были мысли сохранить картинку в rust-коде и переоткрыть ее в ruby-коде, но это выглядит как-то неправильно

```
extern crate image;

use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn process() {
  let mut img = image::open(&Path::new("in.png")).ok().expect("Opening image failed");  
  let filtered = img.crop(730, 50, 400, 500).grayscale();
  filtered
}
```

ruby:

```
require 'ffi'

module First
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'target/release/libembed.so'
  aa = attach_function :process, [], :pointer
  p aa
end

First.process

puts 'Ruby done!'
```

Comment: То, что вы делаете, очень похоже на назначение [minimagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick).

Comment: Спасибо, я знаю, что готовые решения уже есть, просто интересно поработать с внешними либами в рамках изучения нового языка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коротко - не выйдет. `image` все манипуляции делает в буфере в памяти, что в принципе логично. Т.е. там не файловый дескриптор, а "толстый" тип. Либо - придётся делать FFI обёртку над ним, что вряд ли кому-то нужно. Если опишете точнее, что пытаетесь сделать - смогу ответить более точно.

Comment: Я планировал написать модуль на ruby для работы с картинками и в дальнейшем использовать его в существующем Rails-проекте. Параллельно с этим изучал rust и когда узнал более подробно про написание либ, то подумал, почему бы и не попробовать реализовать обработку картинок в rust-либе. Вот только раздел работы с файлами в случае с FFI так и остался непонятен. Видимо придется сохранять картинку-результат rust-либы куда-нибудь в public, а на выход отдавать URL на нее, исключив в ruby-модуле какие-либо постпроцессы

Comment: Нужен ли Rust, если есть gem vips?

Comment: @Nakilon Может и не нужен. Rust это хорошо, но как по мне не должно быть самоцелью.

Comment: @arnage Так какие операции вы планируете делать с этой либой? Что вы планируете делать с картинками в Ruby?

Comment: Я планировал POST-запросом отправлять файл на другие сервера для резервирования результирующей картинки. Но теперь уже и сам не знаю, что лучше - откинуть rust и использовать ruby и vips или выполнять этот запрос в самом rust-скрипте (что сделает его фактически неуниверсальным и заточенным, как минимум, на конфиг с адресами серверов)

Comment: Вам, фактически, нужен байтовый буфер как результат трансформации. Image не является им, точнее - является далеко не только им. Вам потребуется либо действительно использовать готовый гем, либо создавать в Rust буфер нужного размера, совместимый с Ruby, после чего выводить туда результаты трансляции и отдавать в интерпретатор.

Answer (score 1):

Если манипуляции какие-то сложные и попиксельные производятся, и потому без имеющихся наработок никуда, то посмотрите на вот эти штуки:

1. http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/objects/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26419441/322020
3. https://github.com/d-unseductable/ruru

Если же нужно выполнять с изображениями нечто вроде ресайза, фильтров и комбинирования, то можно использовать `gem vips`. Хотя оно и "рисовать" немного умеет: https://github.com/jcupitt/ruby-vips/blob/master/lib/vips/methods.rb